# Surface integral of a scalar function.

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

I was doing this question,

**Evaluate the surface integral $\int \int_S 3z(d\sigma)$, where the surface $S$ is the portion of the plane $2x+y+z=2$ lying in the first octant.**

The way I approached this question was that I took small elemental triangles being projected from the XY-plane, like this,
[image]

Here I multiplied the length of hypotenuse $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ with $dz$ and then substituted $x=\frac{2-z}{2}$ and $y=2-z$, and the resulting expression is,

$S=3\int_0^2z\sqrt{\frac {5(2-z)^2}{4}}(dz)$

However, after evaluating the integral, I am getting an incorrect answer of $2\sqrt 5$. However, the correct answer is $2\sqrt 6$.
So please help me spot my mistake. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the choice of substitution. Why should both $x$ and $y$ only depend on $z$?

Comment: If you have a triangle with area $S$ in the $xy$-plane, the projection of the triangle onto a plane $\sigma$ (in the direction orthogonal to the $xy$-plane) has area $S \left| \sec \theta \right|$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the $xy$-plane and $\sigma$. You need to evaluate $\iint_D 3 (2 - 2 x - y) \left| \sec \theta \right| dx dy$, where $D$ is the projection of the triangle $\mathcal S$ onto the $xy$-plane (also in the direction orthogonal to the $xy$-plane).

Comment: @Maxim Thanks, it really did help a lot. The problem was that I was not taking the projection of dz along the elemental area, and that is why the answer that I got was somewhat smaller than the actual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is indeed $2\sqrt6$, derived here using this well-known [formula](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/surfaceintegrals.aspx). With $z=f(x,y)=2-2x-y$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\iint_S 3z\,\mathrm d\sigma&=\int_0^1\int_0^{2-2x} 3(2-2x-y)\sqrt{1+{f_x}^2+{f_y}^2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\[1ex]
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{2-2x}3(2-2x-y)\sqrt{1+(-2)^2+(-1)^2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\[1ex]
&=3\sqrt6\int_0^1\int_0^{2-2x}(2-2x-y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\[1ex]
&=3\sqrt6\times\frac23=\boxed{2\sqrt6}
\end{align}$$